# How to pop out some activities

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I need to do the following: I have 5 activities and I call them like this A->B->C->D->E but when activity E finishes, then it should return to activity B keeping A first, like this: A->B. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: I've already tried clearing all the stack with intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

And then launched those 2 activities.

Comment: Don't know why you got down voted, its a good question. Thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Don't create a new task.